# Echo get_the_category() outside of loop (global?)

Tags: globals, categories

Trying to grab `get_the_category()` within the loop and post to the byline within the header.

```
// file1.php
<div>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php echo $list_categories ; // THIS DOES NOT WORK ?>
</div>

// file2.php
<article>
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $category_array = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
            $category_list = array();
            foreach ( $category_array as $categories ) {
                $category_list[] = get_cat_name( $categories );
            }
            $lister = implode(' • ', $category_list);
            $list_categories = $lister;

            echo $list_categories; // THIS WORKS

        endwhile; endif;
    ?>
</article>
```

What am I missing? It is not echoing on file1.php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that `the_title();` can parse in file1.php outside of the loop, so why can't the category and ID? The following solved my issue.

```
// file1.php
<div>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php
        $category_array = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
        $category_list = array();
        foreach ( $category_array as $categories ) {
            $category_list[] = get_cat_name( $categories );
        }
        $lister = implode(' • ', $category_list);
        $list_categories = $lister;
        echo $lister ;
    ?>
</div>

// file2.php
<article>
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile; endif;
    ?>
</article>
```

Alternatively, to pass the category link, you could use the following (warning, changed variables below):

```
<ul>
    <?php
        // get post categories
        $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
        foreach ( $cats as $category ) {
            echo "<li>";
            $current_cat = get_cat_name($category);
            $cat_link = get_category_link($category);
            echo "<a href='$cat_link'>";
            echo $current_cat;
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: or in other words, the relevant globals are set to the first post in the results of the query which what makes this kind of code work even before the loop had started, but you could also start the loop and then rewind it,

Comment: Great point. However, Isn't loop rewinding an outdated function? I could be mistaken.

Comment: just because it is used rarely doesn't mean it should not be used ;) IIRC it just change the place counter and sets the globals to the right post again.

Comment: Great point again, will check it out. Thanks Mark!